# How do I compile a GitHub project?

Tags: java

I've tried for few hours.. and failed. i can't seem to get it to work. ( in NetBeans)

I've added libraries that creator pointed out, source and nbproject - I get errors.

Can someone tell me what to do step by step? Thank you in advance.

LINK TO GITHUB: https://github.com/lucidexploration/JonBot-NG

(   i've tried adding it - I downloaded the zip from github then I created new project in netbeams (selected as just Java) then I went to "files" tab and dragged and dropped down src folder from zip i downloaded from GitHub then nbproject and the rest. I've got an JAVADOC error. )

Comment: I think you would be better off asking the guys that own the GitHub repository...

Comment: There's nothing special about projects on GitHub.  You would think the guy would use Gradle or Maven to set up the build, though.

Comment: There are compilation instructions given on the link. Scroll a bit down. Also, this is not a programming question. Downvoting.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: https://github.com/lucidexploration/JonBot-NG#compilation-instructions

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Install git into your system

Step 2 : Clone the project into your system

```
git clone https://github.com/lucidexploration/JonBot-NG.git
```

You are almost done,

Step 3: Import the project into your workspace using IDE.

Everything is ready, enjoy coding.

Comment: Thanks, I want to "build it" and get the progrma to work. I don't know any code.

Comment: IDE will help you on that. search google ;)

Comment: I imported everything one folder by one and I get javadoc error. Can you help me via email or PM?

Comment: javadoc error! would you mind to post it here itself?

Comment: [>>IMGUR LINK TO what I did now<<<<<](https://imgur.com/oXmMEch) 
I think I didn't import any source files.. only libraries that creator of project specified on GitHub.

Comment: you are r8, you did not import

Comment: my "files" tab closed, near "Projects". How can I import from zip everything?

Comment: @lobo follow the steps i wrote. google it for importing

Comment: Where do I type this command?

Comment: Ok i cloned it in github bash i created new project from git repository...
it asks if i want to create main class etc. New project is without ANY trace from git suff @Subhrajyoti

Comment: please follow this - https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/ No need to create project

Comment: I did EVERYTHING there. Can you lookup github link i provided? Maybe its not project.. Please just look into it.

Comment: ?? Di you look into it?